# how to implement both onclickevent and ontouchevent for grid view in android

Tags: android, gridview

I want to implement a gridview in which I display icons which on clicking will perform the desired actions.Also I want a OnTouchListner.I want to implement a UI in which user can either click the images(icons) displayed or slide the menu.But during the interaction i need to capture his finger movements
Can I implement in this way??

```
//This is the setOnItemClickListener block
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Log.d("Click Event","Testing");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Position = " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    gridview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {//MY CODE  });
```

After the edit :

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sAcceleration = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        sGravity = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY);
        sPressure = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE);
        //sArea = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_AREA);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setVerticalSpacing(20);
        gridview.setHorizontalSpacing(20);
        gridview.setNumColumns(4);
        gridview.setStretchMode(3);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new GridView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Log.d("Click Event","Testing");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Position = " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        gridview.setOnTouchListener(new GridView.OnTouchListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int index = event.getActionIndex();
                int pointerId = event.getPointerId(index);
                int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);

                switch(action) {
                    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) :
                        storeData(String.valueOf(event.getRawX()),String.valueOf(event.getRawY()));
                        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Coordinates = (" + String.valueOf(event.getRawX())+ " , "+ String.valueOf(event.getRawY())+ ")");
                        storeData(String.valueOf(event.getSize()),"area");
                        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Area covered = " + event.getSize());
                        storeData(String.valueOf(event.getPressure()),"pressure");
                        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"getPressure() = " + event.getPressure());
                        //Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Axis Pressure = " + event.AXIS_PRESSURE);

                        return true;
                    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) :
                        storeData(String.valueOf(event.getRawX()),String.valueOf(event.getRawY()));
                        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Coordinates = (" + String.valueOf(event.getRawX())+ " , "+ String.valueOf(event.getRawY())+ ")");
                        storeData(String.valueOf(event.getSize()),"area");
                        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Area covered = " + event.getSize());
                        storeData(String.valueOf(event.getPressure()),"pressure");
                        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"getPressure() = " + event.getPressure());
                        //Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Axis Pressure = " + event.AXIS_PRESSURE);

                        return true;
                    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) :
                        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Position testing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        storeData("-100000","-100000");
                        storeData(String.valueOf(event.getRawX()),String.valueOf(event.getRawY()));
                        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Coordinates = (" + String.valueOf(event.getRawX())+ " , "+ String.valueOf(event.getRawY())+ ")");
                        storeData(String.valueOf(event.getSize()),"area");
                        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Area covered = " + event.getSize());
                        storeData(String.valueOf(event.getPressure()),"pressure");
                        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"getPressure() = " + event.getPressure());
                        //Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Axis Pressure = " + event.AXIS_PRESSURE);

                        return true;
                    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) :
                        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Movement occurred outside bounds of current screen element");
                        return true;      
                    default : 
                        return false;
                    }
            }

        });

    }
```

Comment: if you return false on a listener, Android will understand the touch will continue propagating, so the other listerner will be fired.So in onTouch you must return false;

Comment: I am Already returning a "false" value :(

Comment: @avnkailash I can see in your setOnTouchListener you are returning "true" sometimes in the switch statement. e.g. "case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) :...return true" This should be return false; for all cases in the OnTouchListner i.e. it should never return true else it will eat up the event and prevent it from bubbling up to the onclick listner

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188648/android-ontouchlistener-onclicklistener-combination-issue)

```
your_txtView.setOnClickListener(new TextView.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});

your_txtView.setOnTouchListener(new TextView.OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN == event.getAction()) {

    } else if (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction()) {
        v.performClick();
    }

    return true;
}
});
```

ofcourse you can change your_txtView into GridView and TextView.OnTouchListener() into GridView.OnTouchListener()

Comment: No change in the behavior of the app.Still they are not working at a time