# Separately highlight nested TextView and ImageView in ListView row

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, imageview, highlight

(Ok, I've researched a lot and found a few answers but nothing really worked for me.. so I've finally opened an account to post here. Thanks to the community for all your answers earlier!)

## Context

I am creating a category selector (ListView with a custom adapter)- each category can have multiple sub-categories and each sub-category can have multiple sub-categories. For the selector, I'm using a ListView with a custom List item - TextView (to display category) and an ImageView (the forward arrow) to indicate if the category has sub-categories - see this image:

[image]

I want the user to do the following actions

(1) Click on the category name to SELECT that category

(2) Click on the forward arrow to SEE all sub-categories (it will re-populate the ListView with all sub-categories)

## Question Starts here

I want the user to see the following highlights/focus on the user does the about two actions (1) and (2)

#### Highlight on action (1)

See this image:

[image]

Highlight the row when the user clicks on the category name/row.
This happens automatically because I've setup

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener()
```

#### Highlight on action (2)

See this image:

[image]

I want the user to see the highlight **only** on the forward-arrow and not the row. I'm able to register the CLICK on the image with

```
imageView.setOnClickListener()
```

in my custom adapter but I'm unable to get the highlight on the forward-arrow

**How do I get this highlight on the ImageView?**

## Code

```
    Activity's onCreate() {
      LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
      View categorySelectView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cat_select, null);
      LinearLayout categorySelectLayout = (LinearLayout) categorySelectView;
      ListView categoryListView = (ListView) categorySelectLayout.findViewById(R.id.list_cat_select);
      CategoryArrayAdapter categoryArrayAdapter = new CategoryArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(), CategoryAdapter.getAllCategories());
      categoryListView.setAdapter(categoryArrayAdapter);
      categoryListView.setOnItemClickListener(categorySelectClickHandler);
    }

CategoryARrayAdapter's getView(int position, View covertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cat_item, parent, false);

    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.cat_name);
    Category catToDisplay = categories.get(position);
    textView.setText(catToDisplay.getName());

    if(catToDisplay.isParent()) {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.cstrow_cat_expand);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cat_expand);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(categoryExpandClickHandler);
        imageView.setFocusable(false); // to make sure the highlight on row shows
        imageView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false); // to make sure the highlight on row shows
    }

    return rowView;
}
```

Comment: Change background for button on click of it. Otherwise set selector for button in xml file.

Comment: using `imageView.SetBackgroudColor(#color)` partially do the trick. I'll have to manually reset the color back to transparent. How I find (and us) the **default system highlight color**? The `android.R.drawable.listSelector` mentions that it is the default color but I get a `ResourceNotFound` exception when is use `getActivity().getResource().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.listSelector)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what I've done. This should be scalable too.

The CategoryArrayAdapter has the following `getView()`

```
    public View getView(int position, View covertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cat_select, parent, false);

        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.cat_name);
        Category catToDisplay = categories.get(position);
        textView.setText(catToDisplay.getName());

        if(catToDisplay.isParent()) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.cstrow_cat_expand);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cat_expand);
            imageView.setOnClickListener(categoryExpandClickHandler);
            imageView.setOnTouchListener(categoryExpandTouchHandler);
            imageView.setFocusable(false); // to make sure the highlight on the item shows
            imageView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false); // to make sure the highlight on the item shows
            imageView.setTag(catToDisplay);
        }

        return rowView;
    }
```

Two things that made this work

1. `imageView.setOnTouchListener()` allows me to set the highlight (thanks Piyush Gupta for pointing out the `setBackgroundColor()` method
2. `imageView.setOnClickListener()` allows me to perform the action when the user clicks on arrow

   ```
   /**
    * This method listens to the TOUCH CLICK on the IMAGEVIEW to give it button like feeling
    */
   private View.OnTouchListener categoryExpandTouchHandler = new View.OnTouchListener() {

   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       switch(event.getAction()) {
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
               v.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.highlight_cat_expand));
               break;
           }
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
               v.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
               break;
           }
       }
       return false;
   }
   };

   /**
    * This method listens to EXPAND IMAGEVIEW CLICK in the LISTVIEW of categories
    */
   private View.OnClickListener categoryExpandClickHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
       // Expanding this category
       ... expand code here ...
   }
   };
   ```

To get the HIGHLIGHT and CLICK to work together, `return false` in `onTouchListener()`. This will pass the touch event to the `onClickListener()`. I got this solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10376887/3393044 **comment by [the thin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1364781/the-thin)**